# Setting site to auto-check out every file uploaded

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, check-out

I'm looking for solution to automatically set all all the files uploaded to one particular sharepoint 365 site as 'checked-out' **without use of Sharepoint designer**.

Thank you.

Comment: Who should they be checked out to? Will these ever need to be checked in?

The simplest way to have items checked out on upload would be to have a required field on the library, the item can't be checked in until this field is populated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To achieve your requirement, you could set the library settings as below of all libraries in the site.

In one library, go to library settings->versioning settings->Check “Yes” for “Require documents to be checked out before they can be edited?”.

After that, when you upload the files to the library, the files will be checked out automatically.